# Make a partly revealed View expandable when swiping out

Tags: android, android-layout, material-design

I an developing a calculator app where its main activity consists of the top part, which is a `RecyclerView` containing the list of expression stacked from bottom in historical manner. The bottom part is a `GridLayout` for the number pad.
I wanted to make the top view expandable when swiping down a la notification pane in android or `BottomSheet` but flipped. The `RecyclerView` should first reveal the top hidden portion and fill the whole screen and if there is more then user can scroll it.

---

**Here is an illustration on what I wanted.**

[image: [1]]

---

**Here is the main layout on what I've tried so far.**

`activity_calculator.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    tools:context="com.akmal02.calc.MainActivity"
    android:animateLayoutChanges="true">

    <!-- The keypad has multiple pane so I enclose them with a ViewPager -->
    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/pad_pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="280dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">

        <include android:id="@+id/page1" layout="@layout/pad_number" />
        <include android:id="@+id/page2" layout="@layout/pad_advanced" />
        <include android:id="@+id/page3" layout="@layout/pad_advanced" />

    </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>



    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/display_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@id/pad_pager" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

How can I achieve is in Android? I checked `SlidingDrawer` but it is deprecated now and it used two views with one as a handle whereas I only need one. Or do I need external library for that?

Comment: Are you using 1 activity and two fragments?  1 activity + 2 views? or? Post some layouts (relevant only) and what you’ve tried so far ./

Comment: It's 1 activity + 2 views. Updated the post to include the main layout source.